# Display x-axis for each subplot when faceting with facet_grid

Tags: ggplot2, time, colors, facet-grid, x-axis

I've got a facet_grid plot with 8 subplots. I set the scale for the y axis as "free_y" while I need the x axis to be the same for each subplot. My issue is that, while every y-axis is shown, only three of the subplots show their x-axis.

[here is my plot as of now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csDyf.png)

Is there a way to make it visible for all 8 of them?
Plus, I'd need to make the fill colour become more intense as we approach nighttime and vs, is there a way to do so?
May I also add a small sun/moon symbol on top of the bars corresponding to dawn/sunset?

Thank you!

This is my code:

```
(plotcircad <- ggplot(circad, aes(x=hourr,y=mean_d)) + geom_col() +
           geom_uperrorbar(aes(ymax=mean_d+std_d), size=0.25, width = 0.25,
                show.legend = FALSE,col="black") +
           xlab("Time slot") + ylab("Mean (sd) distance from nest (m)") +
           facet_wrap(~ring,scales = "free_y")) + 
           theme_classic() + 
           theme(axis.line.x = element_line(colour = 'black', size=0.5, linetype='solid'),
                 axis.line.y = element_line(colour = 'black', size=0.5, linetype='solid')) + 
           theme(panel.background = element_blank())
```

And here is a part of my dataset (it seems that I'm unable to share it as a code or an Excel file so it's just a picture of it)

[part of my dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPtKl.png)

Comment: I looks like the plot image shows a `facet_wrap()` instead of the grid layout. Could you share a minimal reproducible example to test possible solutions?

Comment: Yes, I got it wrong. It is a facet_wrap() indeed, same issue as I stated before though. I'll edit my question to add a minimal reproducible example!

Comment: (the dataset is huge so I won't be adding it but it's basically specimens (the H code on top of the subplots), daytime time slots in the x-axis and distances (m) in the y-axis)

Comment: Could you instead attach a much smaller dummy dataset that works with your code to illustrate the problem?

Comment: Sure, I'll slim it down a tad

Comment: The code is mostly fine, but it would be convenient to have an approximation to `circad` that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I tried to create a dummy dataset as a code but my Rstudio isn't working properly right now, so I attached part of my original dataset as a picture (sorry)